# Applications of schemes to mathematical physics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, mathematical-physics, schemes

Could anyone cite some applications or developments in mathematical physics or string theory that use schemes?

I find curious the fact that while  things like  derived algebraic geometry and stacks  have certain applications to mathematical physics I cannot find such applications for the case of (underived) schemes.

Just to clarify: I know that for example you can have Calabi-Yau threefolds that are projective algebraic varieties and that in some sense algebraic varieties $\subset $ schemes $\subset $ stacks. However I am looking for specific (underived) scheme constructions like Fano schemes, Hilbert schemes, scheme-theoretic interesections etc

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer are you expecting.. Classical schemes are particular examples of derived schemes / stacks.

But maybe something more down to earth - (compact) Calabi-Yau threefolds show up in physics and they're projective - so they're cut out by equations in projective space.

Comment: Yes, I know that  lot of Calabi-Yau threefolds are usually projective algebraic varieties and that in some sense algebraic varieties $\subset $ schemes $\subset $ stacks. However I am looking for specific underived scheme constructions like Fano schemes or Hilbert schemes or scheme-theoretic interesections,